# How to stop Change Tracking of a certain Property based on a runtime condition

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an entity like this:

```
public class Payment : DataEntity<long>
{
    public short PaymentTypeID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(PaymentTypeID))]
    public virtual PaymentType PaymentType { get; set; }

    public short PaymentStatusID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(PaymentStatusID))]
    public virtual PaymentStatus PaymentStatus { get; set; }
}
```

Based on a business requirement I need to be able to show a different value for `PaymentType`  when the `PaymentStatus` has a certain value without changing that value in the database.

I tried doing this:

```
private PaymentType paymentType;

[ForeignKey(nameof(PaymentTypeID))]
public virtual PaymentType PaymentType { get; set; }
{
    get { return paymentType; }
    set { paymentType = PaymentStatusID == (short)PaymentStatuses.Pending ? value : new PaymentType { Name = "N/A" }; }
}
```

This seems to work until I tried saving a different thing that had a `Payment` in the `EF` `Change Tracking`. `EF` tries save a new `PaymentType`... of course.

Changing this value in the UI is not really an option as that would require making sure that any additional `Views` that get added by future devs maybe years down the road, will need to remember to do this. Failure to do so has significant legal implications and really needs to check for this condition at the `Entity` level.

So the question is, is there an easy way to tell `EF` not to track changes for this property when it meets this condition? The 2 options that I can think of is to add an `[NotMapped]` property that checks for this condition, but again, this would require any future dev to remember to use this property over the original... so not really an option. The other option is to override all of the `EF` `SaveChanges` methods and check for those things there? That second option seems doable but is a lot of work... so before I embark on that journey, I am hoping that someone has some secret sauce that I don't know about? Maybe at the `DbContext` `OnModelCreating` level or even better, at the actual `Entity` `Property` level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After messing around with the `EF` `API`, I figured it out.

First, I changed my `getter`/`setter` to be:

```
public virtual PaymentType PaymentType
{
    get { return PaymentStatusID == (short)PaymentStatuses.Pending ? paymentType : new PaymentType { Name = "N/A" }; }
    set { paymentType = value; }
}
```

Then in the `DbContext` I added this mapping in `OnModelCreating`:

```
var paymentTypeMetadata = modelBuilder.Entity<Payment>().Metadata.FindNavigation(nameof(Payment.PaymentType));
paymentTypeMetadata.SetField("paymentType");
paymentTypeMetadata.SetPropertyAccessMode(PropertyAccessMode.Field);
```

Comment: Starting with v3.0, EF Core uses backing field by default, so you don't really need that fluent configuration code. The only real change needed is the way you implement the property.